# If I hate hats, do I lose them?

Tags: support, winter-bash

If I decide that I hate hats and I don't want to see them good on me. But what happens if I later learn to stop worrying and love the hats? Do I lose any hats I earned before hating hats? And do I miss any hats I may have earned while hating hats? Or if I hate hats, are you still giving me hats I may not want, but just keeping them all to yourselves?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All that *I hate hats* does is hide the festivities. You won't see hats and won't be told about new hats you've earned. You won't be listed on the leaderboard and your profile won't show the *hats* link (even for people that do love hats).

Re-enabling the hats will return all your hats in full glory. Any hats you earned while in denial will also be awarded.

Comment: TIL Hating hats is not enough to fight the magic of winterbash

Comment: It does a bit more than disable the JS, but in essence this is correct.

Comment: @balpha: right; I meant that the hats won't be visible and you won't be notified. I'll reword.

Comment: @balpha just to be sure, as it's now retagged, this still applies in this year, right?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245191/115866

Comment: Thanks @balpha and regarding tags, is this indeed correct to retag questions like this one (and the one you linked to now too, actually) as the "generic" [tag:winterbash] so they can be used in future Winter Bashes?