# Leaderboard (presumably) displaying users who opted-out of Winter Bash

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022, winterbash-leaderboard

Over the past few days, I have come across several users who are in the [Network-wide Leaderboard](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) but have no hats shown in their activity page (**i.e. no [beanie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdqD.png) on their activity page *on a site where I have an account***).

Presumably, these users [opted-out of hats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zci6V.png) *unless there's some other bug involved here*.

It was [confirmed during WB2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245153/can-other-people-see-my-hats-even-if-i-hate-them/245191#245191) that those who opted out of Winter Bash will not be shown on the leaderboard.

> If by that logic a user doesn't participate on a particular site, then behind the scenes we still record what hats they deserve, but these are not surfaced in any way. In particular, on the given site
>
> - the user doesn't see people wearing hats
> - the user doesn't wear a hat
> - the user doesn't have hats in their profile on that site
> - **the user doesn't appear in that site's leaderboard**
> - the user's (deserved) hats do not count towards the site's Leaderboard position
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

Has anything changed?

---

Also, note that users who choose not to wear a hat but did not opt-out will still have a [beanie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdqD.png) on their Activity page that displays their list of hats when clicked.

<sup>I intentionally did not link to any specific users I came across in the Network-wide Leaderboard who opted out of hats as it wouldn't be nice to do so.</sup>

Comment: What about users who choose to not wear them but still earn them through normal activities? I choose to not wear them this year but I am not opting out.

Comment: @JoeW The users who opted-out have [no beanie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdqD.png) on their activity page, i.e. you can’t see their list of hats. I can see yours on your activity page, hence I can tell you didn’t opt-out.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @Catija [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19184094/leucippus?tab=topactivity) ([#230, 13 hats](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=13)) and [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18086074/david-clyde?tab=topactivity) ([#230, 13 hats](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=13)).

Comment: `It was confirmed during WB2014 that those who opted out of Winter Bash will not be shown on the leaderboard.` - It says: "the user doesn't appear in ***that site's*** leaderboard", which is different from the "Network Leaderboard"; also you can take hats off on one site, but not elsewhere, along with completely opting out.

Comment: The first one seems to have them on on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/148155/leucippus) as does the [second one](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1127272/david-clyde).

Answer (score 1):

Rob seems to have pointed you in the right direction. Both of the users you gave me as examples seem to only have hats disabled on Stack Overflow but do have them enabled on other sites, such as Math.

And, looking at their hats, none were awarded on SO, they were all awarded on Math or TeX. In both cases, Math seems to be their primary site but I'm not sure why they disabled hats on SO specifically.

For the time being, I'm going to say that there's not a bug here but if you happen to find other people we can look into, let us know.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I don't think there's a way for the mentioned users to "disable" hats specifically on one site and enable them on another. The "No hats for me, please" is a network-wide opt-out. It appears that the issue now is that the beanie isn't being displayed across the network for the two users since they *didn't* opt-out of hats.

Comment: It's impossible to opt out on single site, the answer is wrong. Perhaps staff can do such thing aka not your fault, but it's still wrong for most readers of the answer.